# Select several fields based on duplicates and find the max value of a column

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2016 and I'm having an issue grouping by more than one col and finding an average while omitting duplicate rows. I have a transaction table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CUST_TRANSACTION]
( 
     [EXTRACT_DATE] [date] NULL,
     [CUSTOMER_ID] [bigint] NULL,   
     [TRANS_NUMBER] [bigint] NULL,
     [CATEGORY] [smallint] NULL,    
     [RANKING] [smallint] NULL 
)
```

Some sample data:

```
EXTRACT_DATE    CUSTOMER_ID TRANS_NUMBER    CATEGORY    RANKING
---------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-31          10001   1000101           4          100
2017-10-31          10001   1000102           4          100
2017-10-31          10001   1000105           4            0
2017-10-31          10001   1000106           4            0
2017-10-31          10002   1000201           4          200
2017-10-31          10001   1000103           5          100
2017-10-31          10001   1000107           5            0
2017-10-31          10003   1000301           5          300
2017-10-31          10003   1000302           5          300
2017-10-31          10004   1000401           7          500
2017-11-30          10004   1000403           7          300
2017-10-31          10001   1000104           8          100
2017-10-31          10004   1000402           8            0
2017-10-31          10003   1000303           8          300
```

The request is to find all the customer_id's that are within a given EXTRACT_DATE and with a RANKING > 1 that exist in more than one CATEGORY.  Then  find the CUSTOMER_ID and the highest CATEGORY that CUSTOMER_ID EXISTS in and finally the number of CATEGORIES the CUSTOMER_ID EXISTS IN

The output should only contain the following two rows:

```
    10001             8        3  
    10003             8        2
```

- CUSTOMER_ID 10001  is in CATEGORY's (4, 5 & 8)
- CUSTOMER_ID 10003  is in CATEGORY's (5 & 8)

Here is the SQL I have so far:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CATEGORY), CUSTOMER_ID, 
    COUNT(CUSTOMER_ID) "Customer_id count"
FROM
    CUST_TRANSACTION
WHERE
    EXTRACT_DATE = CONVERT(datetime, '2017-10-31')
    AND ranking > 1
GROUP BY
    CUSTOMER_ID, CATEGORY
HAVING
    COUNT(CUSTOMER_ID) > 1
```

Output:

```
CATEGORY    CUSTOMER_ID Customer_id count 
----------------------------------------
4                10001     2
5                10003     2
```

I'm getting the correct CUSTOMER_ID's, but not the MAX CATEGORY or correct count of the number CATEGORIES the CUSTOMER_ID EXISTS in. Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with script

```
select MAX(CATEGORY), CUSTOMER_ID, count(CUSTOMER_ID) "Customer_id count"
from
(select distinct CUSTOMER_ID, CATEGORY
from CUST_TRANSACTION
where EXTRACT_DATE = Convert(datetime, '2017-10-31' )
and ranking > 1
)
group by CUSTOMER_ID
having count(CUSTOMER_ID) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.  The SUB-SELECT is what I was having issues with.  All I did was add  "AS X" after the ')' of the SUB-SELECT to address the following error: "Incorrect syntax near the the keyword 'group' ".  After adding that, the code returned the correct output.  I also added a fifth customer_id and assigned them to CATEGORY 5 & 6, something other than CATEGORY 8 of the other two just to test the max and the SQL returned this new CUSTOMER_ID with a count of 2 and MAX CATEGORY of 6.  Great!